# COUNTIF with IMPORTRANGE with date range and unique ID criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I haven't been able to find a solution to get this formula to work after multiple days of searching. The google spreadsheet we use is large and used by many people so I would like to keep this in a separate google sheet using `IMPORTRANGE`.

Data Needed:
Count of assignments a specific user completed within 7 days and after 7 days based on a start and end date.

Where I'm running into issues:
I simplified the equation by using a small data set in the same sheet to see the main issue. When giving a range for the user # the formula doesn't work anymore. When only comparing it to one user # at a time it does.
For example:
This doesn't work:

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C-B2:B,"<7",A2:A,E2)
```

This one does but needs to have the range for the table to work:

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C-B2:B,"<7",A2,E2)
```

[image: Example Table]

I might be going about this all wrong. Any help I could get is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **E2**: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>""))`
- **F2** and drag down: `=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(DAYS(FILTER(C$2:C,$A$2:$A=$E2),FILTER(B$2:B,$A$2:$A=$E2))),"<=7")`
- **G2** and drag down: `=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(DAYS(FILTER(C$2:C,$A$2:$A=$E2),FILTER(B$2:B,$A$2:$A=$E2))),">7")`

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you! This helped so much!!! I have just one other question. Is it possible to add an ISBLANK to this formula? Right now the formula is picking up blank cells for column C if there is no date.